# Two optional One-To-One Mapping Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to build a sample project related to bank activities.

A bank account can be opened by a customer that can be an individual (fiscal person) or a legal entity (enterprise).

I have created 4 tables:

- **customer_type**
- **customer**
- **customer_individual**
- **customer_legal_entity**

[image]

The idea is that the Customer apart from id, has only a foreign key that map the customer_type.

When a new customer must be saved on db, the pk of the **customer** table (id_customer) value must be set with:

- id_customer_individual if the customer is an individual
- id_customer_legal_entity if the customer is a legal entity

To avoid conflicts, id_customer_individual and id_customer_legal_entity uses the same sequence to generate the id value.

Customer have **two one-to-one optional relationships** based on the customer_type.

- a one-to-one relationship with customer_individual
- a one-to-one relationship with customer_legal_entity

CustomerType:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "id_customer_type", nullable = false))
@Table(name = "customer_type")
public class CustomerType extends TypeEntity {

}
```

Customer:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_customer", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_customer_type", nullable = false)
    private CustomerType customerType;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @MapsId
    private CustomerIndividual customerIndividual;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    @MapsId
    private CustomerLegalEntity customerLegalEntity;

}
```

CustomerIndividual:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_individual")
public class CustomerIndividual {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_customer_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_customer_seq", sequenceName = "id_customer_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id_customer_individual", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "fk_nationality", nullable = false)
    private Integer fkNationality;

    @Column(name = "fk_residence", nullable = false)
    private Long fkResidence;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_sex_type", nullable = false)
    private SexType sexType;

    @Column(name = "birth_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone_number", nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;
    
}
```

CustomerLegalEntity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_legal_entity")
public class CustomerLegalEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_customer_legal_entity", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "fk_headquarters", nullable = false)
    private Long fkHeadquarters;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    private String name;

}
```

I firstly save a Customer Individual, then I Create a new Customer instance and set the necessary fields.

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.setCustomerType(customerTypeService.getReferenceById(1));
customer.setCustomerIndividual(customerIndividual);
return customerRepository.save(customer);
```

but when saving the Customer the following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.hyperbank.accounts.customer.entity.Customer.customerLegalEntity]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the SequenceGenerator to **Customer** id and moved the optional one-to-one relationships from **Customer** to **CustomerIndividual** and **CustomerLegalEntity**.

Customer:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_customer_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "id_customer_seq", sequenceName = "id_customer_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id_customer", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_customer_type", nullable = false)
    private CustomerType customerType;

}
```

CustomerIndividual:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_individual")
public class CustomerIndividual {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_customer", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "fk_nationality", nullable = false)
    private Integer fkNationality;

    @Column(name = "fk_residence", nullable = false)
    private Long fkResidence;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_sex_type", nullable = false)
    private SexType sexType;

    @Column(name = "birth_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false)
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone_number", nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;
    
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_customer")
    @MapsId
    private Customer customer;
    
}
```

CustomerLegalEntity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_legal_entity")
public class CustomerLegalEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_customer", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "fk_headquarters", nullable = false)
    private Long fkHeadquarters;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_customer")
    @MapsId
    private Customer customer;
    
}
```

On the service I firstly save the customer, then I set it to the CustomerIndividual and the id of CustomerIndividual is correctly mirroring the id of Customer.

```
public CustomerIndividual save(CustomerIndividual entity) {
    Customer customer = customerService.saveWithTypeCustomerIndividual();
    entity.setCustomer(customer);
    entity = repository.save(entity);
    return entity;
}
```